# .NET Core RedirectToAction not redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this code where I want to delete a User and afterwards redirect to the index page.
The same return statement gets already used in other methods but it its not working in this one...
When I use debug mode the method gets called, but not redirecting.

```
[HttpDelete]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUser()
{
    //var packages = await packageService.GetPackagesCreatedByUserAsync(User.GetUserId());
    //if (packages.Any(p => p.PackageSubscribers.Count > 0))
    //    return Forbid();

    //userService.Logout(User.GetUserId(), HttpContext);
    //await userService.RemoveUser(User.GetUserId());

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

Comment: `RedirectToActionResult("ActionName", "ControllerName", null);` follow this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpDelete]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUser()
{
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must follow this syntax

```
RedirectToActionResult("ActionName", "ControllerName", some_options);
```

The nameof keyword as in Microsoft's documentation

> Use nameof in place of string. A string literal or constant that
>   matches the name of a parameter of the containing method or the name
>   of a property of the containing type is used as an argument to a
>   method.

Example:

Instead using magic string like this

```
public Book(string title)
{
    // Violates rule CA1507
    Title = title ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("title", "All books must have a title.");
}
```

We use

```
public Book(string title)
{
    // Resolves rule CA1507 violation
    Title = title ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(title), "All books must have a title.");
}
```

Or use in webapi

```
// POST: api/Todo
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
{
    _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = item.Id }, item);
}
```

> The preceding code is an HTTP POST method, as indicated by the
>   [HttpPost] attribute. The method gets the value of the to-do item from
>   the body of the HTTP request.
>
> The CreatedAtAction method:
>
> Returns an HTTP 201 status code, if successful. HTTP 201 is the
>   standard response for an HTTP POST method that creates a new resource
>   on the server.
>
> Adds a Location header to the response. The Location header specifies
>   the URI of the newly created to-do item. For more information, see
>   10.2.2 201 Created.
>
> **References the GetTodoItem action to create the Location header's URI. The C# nameof keyword is used to avoid hard-coding the action
>   name in the CreatedAtAction call.**